# Combine randomized evenly distributed numbers into one array

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic

I have N arrays (technically, STL containers) of evenly distributed items (std::random_shuffle). Then I go over these arrays and using some logic which is not related to these items pick different amount (from 0 to K) of these items and push it to the resulting array. Is this resulting array represents an array of evenly distributed items?

pseudocode:

```
std::vector<int> userInput;
userInput.push_back(1,3,6);
std::map<int, vector<int>> storage;
std::vector<int> result; 
for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (auto j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        vec.push_back((i+j)*(10*(i+1)));
    }
    std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    storage.emplace(std::make_pair(i, std::move(vec));
}
for (auto k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
{
    vector<int> indices = someLogicHere(storage[k],userInput))
    for (auto index : indices)
    {
        result.push_back(storage[k][index]);
    }
}
```

Let's assume the std::random_shuffle provides us with uniform distribution
Is "result" vector evenly distributed?

Comment: Could you post your algorithm in code or pseudocode?

Comment: Underspecified. If the vectors are as presented in your pseudocode, the values in `storage[k]` are correlated with `k`, and there is no indication that the size of the vector returned from `someLogicHere(storage[k])` is independent of `k`. Indeed, `someLogicHere` can inspect the individual values of `storage[k]`, so it could introduce bias directly. I don't see how `random_shuffle` is relevant at all (but consider switching to `shuffle` anyway.)

Comment: as stated above, the logic is not related to the values stored in the vector but related to the keys only. Let's say someLogicHere picks up values from user input (a list of keys to take) and only if the "key mod 2 == 0"

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether `someLogicHere(storage[k],userInput))` respects the uniform distribution or not.

There is nothing in your pseudocode that alters the shuffling once is done. This seems to be guaranteed by your statement that "the logic is not related to the items", but the pseudocode itself does not guarantee the same.

In general, though, *any* bias introduced by `someLogicHere` will remove uniformity, because the initial sets have maximum entropy.